# Can I access my phone's antenna to transmitt a sinewave through an app

Tags: android

say I want to send a sinewave at particular some frequency that's in the range of WiFi/LTE/whatever. Surely my phone app is able to do this, what prevents me from building an app to access the antenna to send whatever?

Comment: Basically Android definitely does not provide an API for this. It will surely be possible to do that when writing a custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized, it could totally be possible that there might be no connection between the software and the antenna. A path by which this might happen could be

microphone -> software -> digital converter or processor -> antenna.

We'll at max be able go send some stuff through the digital convertor or modulator and get the antenna to send out bogus signals .